# What does Ctrl + Alt + F10 do on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: shortcut-keys, intellij

I have Intellij Idea, which has its own shortkeys bound to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd>, and I got some weird screen blackout after pressing these keys on my Ubuntu.

I was only able to switch my screen back after pressing <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>.

What does this key combination do? How can I disable it?

Comment: in this case I have so far pressed Ctrl + Alt + Del and unfortunately lost all unsaved data every time. Your way (Super + F2 btw for me Super + F1 woks) seems to me to be better in his regard.

Comment: I tried to bind this key combination for the 'Turn off microphone' action (via the Globalse shortcut menu) but it didn't work. The same thing happens as you described in the question. (i escape with Ctrl+Alt+F1 then)

Comment: I would say it's very odd to be integrating a desktop distro where you can shoot yourself in the foot like that, I can hardly see why keeping this option active by the default installation is warranted. I mean, it's a rather terrible dead-end for the typical end user.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

These keys switch to virtual consoles, in as far as these are active. In a default installation of Ubuntu, no consoles are set up above <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd>, which is why you see nothing more than a blinking cursor after pressing that keyboard combination. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> or simply <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to return to your graphical desktop. You have virtual consoles available on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> up to <kbd>F6</kbd>.

Comment: Is there a way to remove these keys? I don't see anything in keyboard shortcuts settings

Comment: btw, what's a point of having these? I am always can open up terminal inside of Linux, why do I need these external ones?

Comment: It is the historical way of multitasking in unix, before graphical environments were started by default. The keybinding is not controlled by your desktop environment, but deeper in the basis system, perhaps at the level of the kernel?

Comment: i need litle modification. to return to your graphical desktop i needet Ctrl+Alt+F1. here in Kubuntue 20.4 not works Ctrl+Alt+F2 or Alt +F2 for that . Maybe Manjaro Linux does work like so?

Comment: @SL5net it indeed depends on how the distro is set up. On standaard Ubuntu, login manager GDM runs on TTY 1, and the user session on TTY 2. Previously, the graphical session was on TTY 7

Comment: On Xubuntu (v 22.04), the graphical session still runs on tty7.

Answer (score 2):

As explained here
https://askubuntu.com/a/1315576/1017209
you could use into your console or sh-batch-file

`setxkbmap -option srvrkeys:none`

to disable all <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>Fxxx</kbd> hotkeys

i have tested this in Kubuntue 20.4

Comment: I wonder if one would miss any of these combination in sane usage scenarios. The one this OP asks about is really pathological ...