# How to Disable ctrl-alt-fx key combinations in 18.04

Tags: keyboard

I have installed an application in 18.04 that requires the use of ctrl+alt+Fn keys in various combinations to function correctly. I would like to disable (or reprogram) the normal system key combination functions at user login for certain users and not others. Can this be done, and if so, how?

Answer (score 2):

Running the command: "setxkbmap -option srvrkeys:none" in a script file that executes on login did the trick.
Also you can use: setxkbmap -option ''  to remove all keyboard options.

Answer (score 0):

I would look in the preferences:

[image]

Scroll down to see whether you find those that are in conflict.

If you can't find them in there, there is dconf, which gives you access to pretty much all those parameters.